# Adding a entry in a v-select in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I want to add the items in a v-select. for example, we dont have any item in a v-select and want to add it extrenaly.

```
 <v-select
  v-bind:label="Intelligence" 
  v-model="IntValues"
  multiple >
  </v-select>
```

When we write like this we will get only empty select list but how to add items into it externally

Here IntValues:[],

Or Editable list, like TodoMVC

Comment: `v-bind:items`?

Comment: @dfsq if I use v-bind: items then I have to bind items with it, in my case I have an empty list and I want to add an item into it.

Comment: Well binding means that the dom and your variable are connected. So whenever you push something into your array, it will get displayed into the dom, it's as easy as that :) You just `push` items into the array ;)

Comment: @AndreyPopov I think for pushing the items into array we need some editable area where we can hold the value and then push it, but with `v-select` when I click it simply open the list which is empty now so I can not even write anything

Comment: As it's written in the docs about [Selects](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects) - you must provide `items` and `model` - the first is a list of possible options, and the latter - your selection. I think the provided answer explains this as well

Answer (score 2):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      selected: null,
      items: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchItems() {
      this.items = [
        "A1",
        "B2",
        "C3"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.3/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs6>
          <v-subheader>Standard</v-subheader>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs6>
          <v-select :items="items" v-model="selected" label="Select" single-line bottom></v-select>
        </v-flex>
        <div @click=fetchItems>FetchItems</div>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

You can modify the items later to update the value.
You can test with clicking the `FetchItem` to see the effect.

Comment: No, I want to add the values to the list dynamically. I want to provide this facility to user to add in the drop-down list

Comment: Ahaa, you need something like this: https://select2.org/tagging ?? I don't think it's possible with vuetify and you need to develop it yourself.

Comment: @AndreyPopov Yes correct something like select2.org/tagging

Comment: Currently not achievable with vuetify and your question is somehow misleading :)

Answer (score 2):

Watchers will do your work, add a watcher to your model and whenever it changes add value to your items.
You can refer this pen, it is using v-combobox which is having power of autocomplete.
https://codepen.io/saurabhtalreja/pen/yLMyJmE

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      select: ['Vuetify'],
      items: [
        'Programming',
        'Design',
        'Vue',
        'Vuetify',
      ],
    }
  },
  watch:{
    select(val,prev){
      console.log('New Input Value is' ,val);
      console.log('Previous Value is' ,prev);
      console.log('Model is = New Input ie. ', this.select);
      console.log('Items Array is', this.items)
      this.items.push(val);
      console.log('New Items are', this.items)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.4.11/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>



<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-combobox
            v-model="select"
            :items="items"
            label="Combobox"            
            outlined
            dense
          ></v-combobox>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in an array variable named `values`, then just assign it to `IntValues`.

ie,
    `this.IntValues = values;`

If you have a single object say `value`, then just push it to the `IntValues`. ie, `this.IntValues.push(value)`.